# Bootstrap 5 navbar toggle button not responding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navbar, responsive, togglebutton

I'm having trouble getting the toggle button in my Bootstrap 5 navbar to work properly. The button appears, but clicking it doesn't show the navigation links on smaller screens. I've followed the Bootstrap documentation and examples, but I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong.

```
`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-      target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-      label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
 <di`your text`v class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-  toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
   <form class="d-flex">
     <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
     <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I needed to include the "bootstrap.bundle.min.js" file.

```
<script src="static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

I did not notice this requirement either.